# Separate line breaks into columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin, text-to-column

I have one cell with text. The text string looks like the following:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply 
dummy text of the printing 
and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum
has been the
industry's standard 
dummy text.
```

I read to use `Text-to-column`, use as delimiter `Other` and fill in by pressing `Alt` `0010` in the Other field.

However, only the first row stays.

My wanted result is:

[image]

Any suggestions how to separate by line break?

Comment: Use Data ► Text to Columns and Other with [ctrl]+J as the delimiter. [ctrl]+J is `CHAR(10)`, the line feed character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Data ► Text to Columns, Delimited.

On the second screen opt for Other with [ctrl]+J as the delimiter. [ctrl]+J is `CHAR(10)`, the line feed character.

On the third screen, choose B1 for a destination.

[image: text_to_columns_line_feed]

Comment: Could this also be done via a formula? Appreciate your reply!